# How can I convert a piece of text into a list of numbers so that "abc" goes to [0, 1, 2] (with a spacebar going to 26) etc in python

Tags: python

So for example the message "hello" becomes [7, 4, 11, 11, 14].
Currently I have this:

```
print("Please enter message (do not use any capital letters or punctuation marks):")
text = input()
letters = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u",
           "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", " "]
# t is the character of the text we are dealing with
t = 0
# le is the letter of the alphabet we are dealing with
le = 0
numbers = []
length = len(text)
for t in range(length):
    for le in range(27):
        if text[t] == letters[le]:
            numbers.append(le)
print(numbers)
```

It doesn't work - inputting "hello" outputs [7, 31, 65, 92].
Any help would be greatly appreciated. If I'm going about this all wrong, apologies I'm a newbie.

Comment: I am getting the right output from your code...

Comment: Frankly, I don't see how the output you posted is even possible. `numbers` only gets appended with `le` which ever gets its maximum value as `26` so how can you have `31` in the list?

Comment: @Tomerikoo That is odd. Dyou mind me asking what you ran it on? I'm using PyCharm

Comment: Pycharm 2018.3.3, Python 3.7.1 on Linux-2.6.32

Comment: BTW, are you familiar with the `lst.index()` method? It would be easier to just do `numbers.append(letters.index(text[t]))` instead of that second for loop (and then you can also just do `for letter in text`)

Comment: you can even define your `letter` array like this in python:  `letters = ["a".. "z", " "]`, so you can easyly support uppercase letters like this: `letters = ["A".."Z","a".. "z", " "]`. I  try your code and it works FINE!

Comment: I opened a new file and copied my code across, works fine now, no clue what was happening before! I'm still gonna take on all these suggestions to improve it, thanks for taking the time to help :)

Answer (score 2):

Your snippet should be working (it does work on my computer too).
Are you sure you ran the correct file? Or maybe you have something else in the code?

In the meantime your code is not really efficient and prone to mistakes.

As you certainly know, everything in a computer is stored in binary format somewhere in a computer, which means as a number. Hence Characters are numbers too.

To know the exact value-character relations, you can check the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/).

In that table, lowercase letters are one after the other in alphabetical order, and the value associated with `'a'` is 97. In python, you can get the integer representing a character using built-in `ord(character)` function.

In your case, you could do:

```py
print("Please enter message (do not use any capital letters or punctuation marks):")
text = input()

numbers = []
length = len(text)
for t in range(length):
    character = text[t]
    if character == ' ':
        value = 26
    else:
        value = ord(character) - 97 # to get 0 for 'a'
    if value >= 26 or value < 0:
        continue  # to ignore non lowercase and non space characters
    numbers.append(value)
print(numbers)
```

A more pythonic version would be (including Peyman Majidi's suggestion) :

```py
text = input("Please enter message (do not use any capital letters or punctuation marks):")

text = text.lower()  # that way you also handle uppercase characters

numbers = []
for character in text:  # you can iterate over strings directly
    value = ord(character) - 97
    if value not in range(26):
        if character == " ":
            value = 27
        else :
            # define value if character is neither a letter nor a space
            # I'll put -1
            value = -1
    numbers.append(value)

print(numbers)
```

You can also generate lists in a different way in python, and here would be the (kind-of) one line equivalent of the `numbers` list creation. It gives the exact same result as above.

```py
numbers = [26 if c == " " else ord(c)-97 if ord(c)-97 in range(26) else -1 for c in text]
```

Comment: This doesn't really help with OP's current code, and also how will you handle the space?

Comment: in the pythonic version, even you can omit the first print and merge it with input!!! Like: `text = input("Please Enter the ...")`

Comment: Thankyou, this is really helpful! I'm gonna have a nice long read through so I fully understand what going on in each step. Making code more pythonic and efficient is something I'm trying to work on, at the moment I'm just making stuff up as I go along using a lot of googling which leads to some pretty dodgy code.